# Toolbar spinner update/refresh

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

Here I create spinner in the toolbar...

```
my_list=new ArrayList<String>();
String[] list={""};

    String sql = "select items from table";
    try {
        mydb = openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor select = mydb.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if (select.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                my_list.add(select.getString(0).toString());
            } while (select.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    } finally {
        mydb.close();
        list=my_list.toArray(new String[my_list.size()]);
    }

    adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item_toolbar, R.id.tvAccount, list);
    adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item_toolbar); 
    spinner_nav.setAdapter(adapter_state);
```

After calling fragment that doesn't have that spinner showed in the toolbar, where I add one record to the table, I cannot refresh the spinner in the toolbar. I am trying to refresh in onResume() and the same code except last three lines. Except those I am using:

```
adapter_state.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Creating of toolbar and onResume is on the MainActivity.